# R: Parse (+eval) string used as args for subset/[. NSE case?

Tags: r, eval, subset, nse

In my app user can provide "subsetting" expression (which consist of mix: variables, names stored in variable - vide `args_input` and `subset_args_input` variables) as arguments to `subset`/`[` functions:

```
df_data <- data.frame("a" = c(1,1,2),
                      "b" = c(3,4,4),
                      "c" = c(5,6,7))

global_data <- list("column_to_extract" = c("b"))

args_input <- "list(df_data, df_data$a %in% c(1), global_data[['column_to_extract']])"
```

My expectation is to get as same result as executing:

```
do.call("[", list(df_data, df_data$a %in% c(1), global_data[['column_to_extract']]))
```

by executing this:

`do.call("[", eval(parse(text=args_input)))`

Also, I've tried something similar with `subset`:

```
subset_args_input <- "list(quote(df_data), quote(a %in% c(1)), quote(global_data[['column_to_extract']]))"

do.call("subset", eval(parse(text=subset_args_input)))
```

1. Both approaches work, but need `eval` + `parse`, which are not safe in case user is allowed to pass any string. Question - could the same results be achieved without `eval` + `parse` combo?
2. Could you (R users:) please have a look at above snippets - are there any unnecessary things/something against R philosophy?

Comment: If you let your users pass R expressions as text you need to parse that text. Obviously you shouldn't do that. I can't comment more with the available information.

Comment: @Roland: thanks for comment. I am looking for the safe solution in which user can pass: name of DF to subset, subset condition, selected "output" column/-s - all of these as strings.

Comment: There is no safe way to do it like that because you'll have to parse and evaluate the subset condition. You need to work on the way the user input is created. For example you could use something like this, where the subsetting functions and the RHS and LHS are separate input (e.g., using a drop-down menu and two text fields): `with(df_data,
     eval(as.symbol(column_to_extract))[
       switch(subfun, 
              "==" = `==`,
              "<" = \`<\`, 
              ">" = \`>\`,
              "%in%" = \`%in%\`)(eval(as.symbol(LHS)), type.convert(RHS))])`.

Comment: Ok, kind of white list with allowed expression - thank you for your comment.